# Anime with a prince and a servant chased by zombies who meet an immortal woman

Tags: kurozuka

I watched an anime show a while back on Crackle, but I can't remember the name. It's not there anymore but I really enjoyed it.

It started out with a teenage prince and his servant running through the woods being chased by zombie like creatures. They came across a house where a beautiful woman lived and asked for shelter. They both fell in love with her. Then, they found out that she was an immortal, and a group of assassins were after her blood. She turned the prince into an immortal as well. When he woke up 1000 years in the future, he couldn't remember anything, but he went on a search for her.

Comment: A guess can  be [Kurozuka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurozuka)...

Comment: That is correct thank you. I knew her name started with a K and I couldn't remember. I'm glad it was answered so quickly thank you.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer for further reference then...

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the grammar reconfiguration as well.

Comment: Okay, I believe we have begun to understand that the constant revisions are unnecessary

Answer (score 5):

It is [**Kurozuka**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurozuka):

> The series begins in 12th century Japan and centers on Kuro, a character based loosely on the legendary Japanese swordsman Minamoto no Yoshitsune. Kuro and his servant, Benkei, meet a beautiful and mysterious woman named Kuromitsu while on the run from Kuro's elder brother, who seeks his life. Kuromitsu and Kuro fall in love, but he soon discovers that she harbors a terrible secret: she is a vampiric immortal. Following an attack by his pursuers, Kuro is badly injured and must imbibe Kuromitsu's blood to save his own life. Kuro is then betrayed and attacked by Benkei, who has been subverted by a shadowy organization called the Red Army, and Kuro's head is severed, which interferes with his transformation into a fully immortal being. [...]

[image: pic]